# How to test custom validation rule in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, tdd

i would like to write a test for my custom rules.

my example looks like this.
I'm check if the user gives the correct current password.

my custom rule:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return Hash::check($value, auth()->user()->password);
}

public function message()
{
    return 'Your current password is incorrect.';
}
```

and the test for this rule:

```
class CurrentPasswordTest extends TestCase
{
   use WithFaker, RefreshDatabase;

   /** @test */
   public function current_password_must_be_valid()
   {  
      $rule = new CurrentPassword();
      $user = factory(User::class)->create(['password' => '1234']);

      $this->assertTrue($rule->passes('current_password','1234'), $user->password);
   }
}
```

but i'm getting an error:

> Tests\Unit\CurrentPasswordTest::current_password_must_be_valid
>   ErrorException: Trying to get property 'password' of non-object

what i'm doing wrong in this example ?

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to log in your user before you can use your `passes()` method - otherwise `auth()->user()` will be null. You can do that using the `be($user)` method like this:

```
/** @test */
public function current_password_must_be_valid()
{  
  $rule = new CurrentPassword();
  $user = factory(User::class)->create(['password' => '1234']);
  $this->be($user);
  $this->assertTrue($rule->passes('current_password','1234'), $user->password);
}
```

It would also be advisable to guard against `null` values in your `passes()` method to prevent errors. If there is no user logged in, it should probably just return `false`.